# Declaring a public type alias for an inner class

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm new to swift and am wondering why i got this error [image: here is my code]

Comment: Post the code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure since you haven't included either your code or the full error message, but it looks like you're trying to declare a public typealias that refers to a private (or at least non-public) type, probably `TimerBuilder`  You need to make sure that the `TimerBuilder` class/struct/whatever it is is public.